# How to scroll draw each SVG path one at a time (chronologically)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg, scroll

This is related to a previous post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32935430/how-to-scroll-and-animate-svg-draw). However, I think it was a bit of a momentous task. So I am breaking it down to smaller chunks.

I have made a simple SVG image that includes one "path" and one "rect" element. The user can draw the lines on and off the window by scrolling up and down the page (scroll down the page for on and up the page for off/"undraw). However, both elements "draw"/animate at the same time. What I want to do is as the user scrolls down the page, the line path draws on, then the "rect" element draws (after), so it's more fluid and chronological.

```
 <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>the single line</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="line.css">

<style>
svg {
  position: fixed;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 50%;
}
/*.line{
  stroke-dashoffset:850;
  stroke-dasharray: 850;
}
.box {
 stroke-dashoffset:1852;
 stroke-dasharray: 1852;
}*/
.all{
 stroke-dashoffset:2702;
 stroke-dasharray: 2702;
}

.straightLine {
  height: 3000px;
  position: relative;
  width: 360px;    
  margin: 40vh auto 0 auto;

}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<main role="article" title="line">
<div class="straightLine">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"

     viewBox="0 0 1280 800" style="enable-background:new 0 0 1280 800;" xml:space="preserve">

<style type="text/css">

    .st0{fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:8;stroke-miterlimit:10;}

</style>
<g class="all">

<path class="st0" d="M54,178h509.6c49.9,0,90.4,40.5,90.4,90.4V428"/>


<rect x="498" y="428" class="st0" width="308" height="162"/>

</g>
</svg>



</div>
</main>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="line.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  //variable for the 'stroke-dashoffset' unit
  var $dashOffset = $(".all").css("stroke-dashoffset");
  //on a scroll event - execute function
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    //calculate how far down the page the user is 
    var $percentageComplete = (($(window).scrollTop() / ($("html").height() - $(window).height())) * 100);
    //convert dashoffset pixel value to interger
    var $newUnit = parseInt($dashOffset, 10);
    //get the value to be subtracted from the 'stroke-dashoffset'
    var $offsetUnit = $percentageComplete * ($newUnit / 100);
    //set the new value of the dashoffset to create the drawing effect
    $(".all").css("stroke-dashoffset", $newUnit - $offsetUnit);
  });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How is this?  You can control when each path starts and finishes drawing by setting the `startPct` and `endPct` percentage values in the `scrollBehaviour` array.

Note: this code assumes you are only using paths and rects.  If you start using other elements, the `calcPathLength()` function will have to be updated.

```js
var scrollBehaviour = [
     {id: 'line1', startPct: 0, endPct: 30},
     {id: 'rect1', startPct: 30, endPct: 60},
     {id: 'line2', startPct: 60, endPct: 80},
     {id: 'circ1', startPct: 80, endPct: 100}
  ];

$(document).ready(function() {

  // On a scroll event - execute function
  $(window).scroll(scrollEventHandler);

  // Call the scroll event handler once at the start to initialise the dash offsets
  scrollEventHandler();

});



function scrollEventHandler()
{
  // Calculate how far down the page the user is 
  var percentOfScroll = (($(window).scrollTop() / ($("html").height() - $(window).height())) * 100);

  // For each lement that is getting drawn...
  for (var i=0; i<scrollBehaviour.length; i++)
  {
    var data = scrollBehaviour[i];
    var elem = document.getElementById(data.id);

    // Get the length of this elements path
    var dashLen = calcPathLength(elem);

    // Calculate where the current scroll position falls relative to our path
    var fractionThroughThisElem = (percentOfScroll - data.startPct) / (data.endPct - data.startPct);
    // Clamp the fraction value to within this path (0 .. 1)
    fractionThroughThisElem = Math.max(fractionThroughThisElem, 0);
    fractionThroughThisElem = Math.min(fractionThroughThisElem, 1);

    var dashOffset = dashLen * (1 - fractionThroughThisElem);

    elem.setAttribute("stroke-dasharray", dashLen);
    elem.setAttribute("stroke-dashoffset", dashOffset);
  }
}



function calcPathLength(elem)
{
  if (elem.getTotalLength)
  {
    // It's a path
    return elem.getTotalLength();
  }
  else if (elem.tagName === "rect")
  {
    // Handle rect elements: perimeter length = w + w + h + h
    return (elem.width.baseVal.value + elem.height.baseVal.value) * 2;
  }
  else if (elem.tagName === "circle")
  {
    // Handle circle elements: perimeter length = 2 * r * PI
    return elem.r.baseVal.value * 2 * Math.PI;
  }
  else if (elem.tagName === "line")
  {
    // Handle line elements: use pythagoras' theorem
    var dx = elem.x2.baseVal.value - elem.x1.baseVal.value;
    var dy = elem.y2.baseVal.value - elem.y1.baseVal.value;
    return Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
  }
  // If you use other elem types, you will have to add support for them here.
}
```

```css
svg {
  position: fixed;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 50%;
}
/*.line{
  stroke-dashoffset:850;
  stroke-dasharray: 850;
}
.box {
 stroke-dashoffset:1852;
 stroke-dasharray: 1852;
}
.all{
 stroke-dashoffset:2702;
 stroke-dasharray: 2702;
}*/

.straightLine {
  height: 3000px;
  position: relative;
  width: 360px;    
  margin: 40vh auto 0 auto;

}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<main role="article" title="line">
<div class="straightLine">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"

     viewBox="0 0 1280 1000" style="enable-background:new 0 0 1280 800;" xml:space="preserve">

<style type="text/css">

    .st0{fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:8;stroke-miterlimit:10;}

</style>
  <g class="all">

    <path id="line1" class="st0" d="M54,178h509.6c49.9,0,90.4,40.5,90.4,90.4V428"/>

    <rect id="rect1" x="498" y="428" class="st0" width="308" height="162"/>

    <line id="line2" x1="652" y1="590" x2="652" y2="790" class="st0"/>

    <circle id="circ1" cx="652" cy="890" r="100" class="st0"/>

  </g>
</svg>



</div>
</main>
```

Comment: Hey Paul. Some great mark-up. Sorry I haven't thanked you for it yet. I've been playing  with it & to understand it  more. One part I can't get my head around is updating the code to include other shape elements like "circle" and "ellipse"and "text". I can update this....

var scrollBehaviour = [
     {id: 'line1', startPct: 0, endPct: 40},
     {id: 'rect1', startPct: 40, endPct: 100},
  ];


but not this....

    // Assume it's a rect.
    // If you use other elem types, you will have to add support for them here.
    return (elem.width.baseVal.value + elem.height.baseVal.value) * 2;
  }
}

Comment: You will need to use different calculations (based on different attributes) for the other element types. For example, for a circle you would need to look at the `r` attribute.  I've updated the example to show how you can determine the element type.

Comment: Honestly, I ought to pay you. Sorry to bother you again Paul. You seem the only person on the WWW who is kind enough to help me, regardless of how irritating I am becoming. 

Just to see if I am understanding this correctly (be gentle I am new to JS) Do I need to add else if (elem.tagName === "rect") for every attribute. This example would be for the rectangle svg element. tagName==="xy" would be for length of the line svg attribute?

Comment: You would check the `tagName` for each SVG element ("line", "circle" etc), then calculate the correct length of the shape using the attributes particular to that shape.  So for circle it would be the `r` attribute etc.  I'll add some additional examples for you.

Comment: Don't be confused about the `.baseVal.value` stuff. It's just how you access the value of an attribute in the SVG DOM.  The DOM is just the internal JS representation of the document.  So if `elem` is pointing at the internal JS version of a `<rect>` element, you can get the `width` attribute using `elem.width.  However the width value is not stored directly in `elem.width` because the width is (potentially) animatable. So the `width` object is more complicated.

Comment: (cont...)  `elem.width.baseVal` is the object that describes the initial value of the attribute before it starts animating. And `elem.width.baseVal.value` is the numerical part of the attribute. As opposed to the units part when the attribute is, for example, `"25px"`.

Comment: This is brilliant. I am starting to really get the hang of this. I am indebted to you. Now, I have one final question. I've checked on the MDN for the text attribute and its elements are x and y <text x="10"  y="20" (similar to the line attribute. However,  my text is not determined as such. It uses transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 635.5942 413.2075). MDN states if y is not provided, it is assumed to be zero. What does this mean and how do I know the coordinates of X and Y?

Comment: The text positioning is being performed by the transform. `<text x="0" y="0" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 635 413)"/>` is equivalent to `<text x="0" y="0" transform="translate(635 413)"/>` which is equivalent to `<text x="635" y="413"/>`.

Comment: Paul. Thank you so much for your time. I am very grateful indeed. I will surely credit you in my dissertation. Your help has been nothing less of AWESOME. 

But I definitely think I have taken enough of your time. 

Cheers Paul!

Comment: NP. Your's welcome.  The best way to thank me is to upvote my answer and accept it (click the green check/tick) :-).  Good luck on your dissertation!.

Comment: Is there a method to alert/do something when the path begins the dasharray and/or completes? I need to trigger animations elsewhere each time each path is completed.