# How to create a line draw effect - Using ScrollMagic & GSAP (GreenSock)

Tags: wordpress, svg, scroll, gsap, scrollmagic

I am starting a web project soon, and there is an element of this site: https://serioverify.com that my client would like to have on their site.

It is the line drawing effect based on scroll positioning.
I have integrated GreenSock & ScrollMagic with my custom theme - but how do I create this line effect, can provide a specific example if required.

Any guidance is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Are you asking how to create the line drawing effect, or how to do it with that combination of libraries? The answer to the first question is with the dash offset trick (search it).  The response to the second is "what have you tried"?

Comment: @PaulLeBeau - Thank you for your quick response, ideally it would be using those libraries, but I haven't tried anything yet as I am unsure where to begin. I plan on pinning a frame, then drawing the line.

But I am open to other ways of creating this effect, I have also been recommended HTML Canvas beziarCurve ?

Comment: Sounds like you want something like this then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32982539/how-to-scroll-draw-each-svg-path-one-at-a-time-chronologically

Comment: Answer found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32982539/how-to-scroll-draw-each-svg-path-one-at-a-time-chronologically By @Paul Lebeau