# How to draw SVG curved using single path?

Tags: css, svg, svg-animate

What I want is in the **following image** -
 [image]

> **I have 3 relative question regarding this**

**1.Can we draw the whole canvas with a `single path`.?**

**2.If we can only draw the whole using more than one path will it be convenient to give them animation?**

**3.In both cases can anyone be kind enough to guide to a proper way with a sample.?**

This is where I have gotten so far... as you can see am not an expert on `SVG` and of course, you can use a circle for the big dot. Thank You in advance.

```css
svg {
  width: 100%;
}

.straightLine {
  height: 3000px;
  position: relative;
}

.st0 {
  fill: none;
  stroke-dashoffset: 3px;
  stroke: #000000;
  stroke-width: 5;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
}
```

```html
<div class="straightLine">
  <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 1280 1000" style="enable-background:new 0 0 1280 800;" xml:space="preserve">
 <g class="all">
 <path id="line1" class="st0" stroke-dasharray="10,9" d="M 35 -17 C 0 190 50 83 600 109 "/>
 <path id="line1" class="st0" stroke-dasharray="10,9" d="M 600 109  c 64.9 0 90.4 40.5 90.4 90.4"/>
 </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: You are likely better off drawing the path in a specialized program, like Illustrator or GIMP, and then exporting it as an SVG. Hand-drawing these lines are possible but also very complicated.

Comment: @Terry I have created that image by my self in **illustrater** , but that is not I wanted. I have some animation to do on the scroll of the page using this `<path>` that's why am looking for a CSS option. So if can do help me.ty

Comment: What kind of animation do you want to do? It wasn't clear in your question. Do you want to animate the path? Or animate the position of the circle along the path?

Comment: @Terry What I want is to draw the line using the scroll of the page connecting some of my images. Like this -
https://stackoverflow.com/a/33054738/7629714

Comment: You can simply animate the line-drawing using `stroke-dashoffset`, without needing to change the path at all: https://css-tricks.com/svg-line-animation-works/. In other words, you draw the full path, and decide the offset value baesd on scroll position.

Comment: @Terry ty for that - It just made my work a lot easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use something like:

```
<path d="M 20 0 v 20 a 30 30 0 0 0 30 30 h 600 a 40 40 0 0 1 0 80 h -140 a 30 30 0 0 0 0 60 h 200 a 40 40 0 0 1 0 80 h -100 a 30 30 0 0 0 -30 30 v 20" />
```

As shown in [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths), paths can contain an arbitrary number of components.

As a summary:

```
M/m    Move current position
L/l    Draw a line
H/h    Draw a horizontal line
V/v    Draw a vertical line
C/c    Draw a cubic Bezier
Q/q    Draw a quadratic Bezier
A/a    Draw a circular/elliptal arc
Z/z    Close path
```

In general, uppercase instructions specify absolute coordinates and lowercase instructions specify relative.

Comment: One more thing, For the circle dot, should we use `<circle>` in `<svg>` or is there a way we can combine it with this `<path>` it self.?

Comment: A filled circle would require a new element. Whether that's done as `<circle>` or as another `<path>` is up to you.

Comment: how can we `position` it exactly at the same place. Can we use `position: absolute` or there is another way in `<svg>`

Comment: Something like `<circle cx="400" cy="50" r="10" />`. [`cx` = center x](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/cx), [`cy` = center y](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/cy), [`r` = radius](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/r).